# Why does Azure logging disable itself every 12 hours?

Tags: azure, logging

Why does Azure have [this ridiculous behavior](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2303959) ? If a customer encounters an error, I can't ask them to repeat it after I go turn the logging back on.

Comment: Your link states the answer `Because of the limited amount of disk space available`.

Comment: So have they never heard of rolling log files? Disk space is not an excuse for completely disabling logging

Answer (score 2):

That is true when you are using the default filesystem for logging. If you set up a storage account and then enable logging you can choose if the logs are sent to the file system or storage.

Take a look at this article under How to Enable Diagnostics

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/